# How to avoid CIRCULAR REFERENCE in TABLEAU using LOOKUP and PREVIOUS_VALUE?

Tags: tableau-api, lookup, circular-reference

**Hello!**

In Excel I have 2 columns C and D with formulas in there for a specific purpose.
As an Example I have here cells C12 and D12 in these 2 columns to show he formulas.

```
C12 = 0.001855 *  B12/E12  + 0.998145 * (C11+D11)
D12 = 0.981119 * (C12-C11) + 0.018881 * D11
```

Let's say the C-column variable is "Running Base" and the D-column variable is the "Growth" and the rows are months. And say I want to copy these formula's to a Tableau worksheet with months in the rows.

You see that C12 is using both it's own previous value C11 (the lag -1 of C) and the lag -1 of D (D11). I can find C11 in the formula in TABLEAU using the PREVIOUS_VALUE function and the previous value of D with the LOOKUP([D],-1) function (the B12 and E12 are not important for the discussion).

Then D12 is also using it's own previous value D11 and both C12 and its previous value C11. Of course we can do similar TABLEAU exercises here, but you already feel a CIRCULAR REFERENCE error coming up ;-).

So, there is no actual CIRCULAR REFERENCE and it's working in Excel. But I do understand why TABLEAU is giving one and I am sure there must be a work-round to this.

Can anybody help please???

Thx very much in advance!!

**Herman Mentink**

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to drop the calculation in `Details` part of the **Marks** and then reference the rows of that field in calculation which doesn't create a circular reference else you are correct tableau will create a circular reference error as behaviour is different from Excel.

Edit----------------------------------------------------------------

Not just a tool tip infact you can use those in calculated fields aswell, Few months back I have implemented same in my report.

A calculation creates 4 rows in my report and I need to do (1st row+4th row) in the same column, so I dropped the calculation in `Detail` on the `Marks` and referred same another calculated field. Just check the below example code:

```
LOOKUP(ATTR([Values]),FIRST()+4) + LOOKUP(ATTR([Values]),FIRST()+1)
```

`Values` is the calculated field now above caluction is referring to Values and picking rows 2 and 5 which I can't use directly on the Values column if I drop `Values` on `Text` in Marks

[image]

In the above image values in `detail` is original calcualtion and the one I used in `text` is the referring to values and displaying.

Comment: Hi Siva! Thx very much for this tip, it feels like I understand your workaround. I have been trying, but not an expert Tableau user. I understand Tooltip uses the detail measures and you can refer to them. The latter is what you mean. Could you maybe relay a very small example of just a few data points using this mechanism plse? would be really appreciated!! Thx very much in advance, Herman Mentink

Comment: Hi Siva! May I thank you again for the effort you have put in! Sorry I respond some late; I finalized a project and then went om holidays with my kids ;-). I still do not get it though, i.e. about how to drop things in text and details in Marks... (and what variable is the calculated field of values?). Is it also possible to email me the simple example in a Tableau file maybe plse, so I can look at it In more detail? hermanmentink@gmail.com Many thx again!!

Comment: @HermanMentink Hi Herman, I can't share the workbook as it has client confidential data, If you can attach or share the workbook, I will try to help you with the calculation.